.mobileconfig issue automatically disconnecting OnDemand VPN
I have configured a .mobileconfig profile for my iOS and Mac devices.
My intention:

Have my VPN connect only on specific domain requests outside of my local home internal network. (these domains are internal resources I want to reach externally, via my internal DNS.)

In my .mobileconfig file I have specified DNS where the VPN should not connect. I have setup an ActionParameters dictionary using the ConnectIfNeeded string.
I have also specified a wildcard for all other domains and used the NeverConnect string.
my config rules look as such:
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>Disconnect</string>
                    <key>DNSServerAddressMatch</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>192.168.0.1</string>
                        <string>192.168.0.2</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>EvaluateConnection</string>
                    <key>ActionParameters</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>DomainAction</key>
                            <string>ConnectIfNeeded</string>
                            <key>Domains</key>
                            <array>
                               <string>internalserver.domain.com</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>DomainAction</key>
                            <string>NeverConnect</string>
                            <key>Domains</key>
                            <array>
                                <string>*</string>
                            </array>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>

Things work, VPN connects on that domain request externally - except the VPN does not disconnect on other domain requests. It remains connected until I either manually disconnect it, or connect to my internal network with the specified DNS.
I'm at a loss as to why the VPN remains connected on other domain requests outside the domains I specified under ConnectIfNeeded .
would anyone have any idea why - or am I missing something above to have the VPN disconnect on other domain requests apart from the ones above?
I have added periods around the * to signify all other domains the VPN should not connect.
However this didn't change anything - and the VPN remains connected if I navigate to the specified internal domain.
